# CakePHP move_uploaded_file returns false

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm new to CakePHP, trying file uploading and `move_uploaded_file` always returns `false`. Here is my code:

**EDIT:** the first line was what was wrong

```
// This line was wrong, should be done after uploading.
$this->request->data['Post']['image'] = $this->request->data['Post']['image']['name']


if($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
    $filename = basename($this->request->data['Post']['image']['name']);
    $filePath = WWW_ROOT . DS . 'files' . DS . $filename;

    if(move_uploaded_file(
        $this->request->data['Post']['image']['tmp_name'],
        $filePath
    ))
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved'));

    else
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved, but image failed'));
}
```

Why isn't it working?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20989968/1239506 it might  help you

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was setting the image name before uploading, seems like it should be done after uploading the file.

```
//move_uploaded_file() stuff...

$this->request->data['Post']['image'] = $filename;

if($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) { //...
```